# Oracle type of Object

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

When creating a type of object, is it possible to declare the type as `TABLE.COLUMNNAME%TYPE`?

e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PROJECT_TYPE IS OBJECT
(
    project_id project.project_id%TYPE,
    project_desc project.project_desc%TYPE
);
```

or I have to specify the type and width at the time of creation? Reason why this question is if table is altered then I have to change to data type and width of type OBJECT as well?

Comment: table.column%type will work fine for after effects of alter statements

Comment: @realspirituals Problem is it does throw error when `table.column%type `is provided as datatype.

Comment: woops... my mistake.. I was blind when reading your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, unfortunately, not possible. You have to provide actual type, you can not reference a `%TYPE` of a table's column.

The reason for that is that both `%TYPE` and `%ROWTYPE` are PL/SQL constructs, which are not supported in SQL.

Comment: hmm! So can this be declared in a package and if it can be declared in a package, can this be accessed from Java if I would want to pass array from Java to a procedure?

Comment: @Polppan Well... I don't think so, because both the type of elements of the TABLE type and the TABLE type itself must be declared at the _database_ level (so you can't use `%ROWTYPE` na `%TYPE`) to be available on the Java side through JDBC. If you declare them in a package, then you won't be able to create `STRUCT` and `ARRAY` descriptors based on those packaged types.

Comment: Thanks and well explained, appreciated.

Comment: Oracle support for collection objects are very limited, don't you think so? And whatever available does seems to be primitive when compared to Java :-)

Comment: @Polppan This is because the databases are, in general, not object-oriented, but data-structures-oriented. There would have to be some dependency tracking if you would be allowed to use `%TYPE` and `%ROWTYPE` in SQL. If you could, then you'll be able to define a table whose column's type is same as some other table's column type. If you dropped the second, you would have problems with the dependency... You could consider using Hibernate and JPA to persist your objects to database, but for that, you'd have to read some tutorial/book.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I do use Hibernate, however for this project, it is plain JDBC.